# Using __str__() in class object n python 3.7

Tags: python, string

I created a class.
After that i instantiated that class by the variable name 'xyz'.
Now is there a way that I can display the name of this variable i.e. **print 'xyz' inside __init__in the class??**

Comment: Please show example code of what exactly you're trying to do. I'm not finding this very clear. Why do you want to display the *name* of the variable?

Comment: Init is used to instantiate stuff, why do you want to print? Please show some code

Comment: So when you do `xyz = MyThing()`, you want `MyThing.__init__()` to print "xyz"? What should it print if you do `MyThing()` by itself with no assignment? What should it print if you do `a = b = c = x.y.z()[1::] = [1,2, MyThing(), 3]`?

Comment: No.  The right hand side of the assignment is executed first, so the code assigning the new object to the name `xyz` comes after the code creating that object.  This means that the code creating the object can't know what name it is being assigned to.  (There are also many circumstances where an object is created but not given an identifier, or is referred to by multiple different identifiers.)

Comment: If you need your class to have a name/identifier associated with each instance, pass a name in. Relying on a variable name is fragile (and as Patrick points out, not even sensical in some cases).

Comment: thanks for your help everyone, I added a name parameter and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Patrick Haugh mentioned in the comments, since the right hand side of the assignment is always executed first and then the assignment is evaluated with the result of that execution there is no (easy) way for the right hand side to know what the variable name would be.

Although not good, if you absolutely need to know this piece of information you can always pass the name as a parameter...

```
xyz = MyClass('xyz')
```

I believe there is a way of solving what you are asking with Metaprogramming, but since I have not experience in that area I wouldn't dare to give you any advice